# How can I concat List<type>?

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

I have this code :

```
protected IList<MyObject> offerte;

offerte = offerte.Union(from MyObject object in MyObjects
                        select object).ToList();
```

but I get an `System.ArgumentNullException` (maybe because I'm adding a IEnumerable<> on a List<>).

So, how can I concat List<>?

Comment: You just forget to initialize your object, there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: -1? Why -1? I can't understand those downvotes...

Comment: Your code has a basic problem (or is incomplete here): you are missing the initialization of your object after its declaration and this is the reason for your exception. The answers below target your second problem: the difference between Union and Concat in LINQ, that is much more interesting! :) Just edit your post appropriately and it won't be downvoted (hopefully)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Union is not concatenation, check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx. Union of 2 sets with same values will produce same exact set for example.

What you need is `Concat` (surprise, surprise):

```
offerte = offerte.Concat(from MyObject object in MyObjects
                    select object).ToList();
```

However, ArgumentNullException will still occur, cause `offerte` is not initialized (check devdigital' answer).

Comment: In fact is strange. With my code (which I thought was wrong) I union a List with a IEnumerable. Then, with the merged result (half List, half Ienumerable) I convert whole in List? Its very strange imo...

Comment: It's not strange. List implements IEnumerable<T> also, and Concat is extension method for IEnumerable.

Comment: Uhm, maybe I don't know how List/IList/IEnumerable works together. Any good tutorial?

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the exception because `offerte` is null. Try:

```
offerte = new List<MyObject>(MyObjects);
```

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the Union and Concatenation is whether you consider your data being sets or sequences.

In case of Union you will merge two sets of data, meaning the if you have one value in both lists than it will be kept only once, so merging `{1, 2, 3}` and `{2, 3, 4}` gives you `{1, 2, 3, 4}` (provided your custom datatype implements the approriate interface and overrides the hash function to enable the comparison for equality in LINQ).

If you want to concatenate your data, then the second part will be just appended to the first par and you will get `{1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4}`.

What exactly do you want to do with your data?

P.S. And you can't get half-Enumerable and half-List, every List is an IEnumerable, since List implements this interface. Since LINQ is evaluated lazily you will get just a query. In your case you force its eager evaluation by calling the `.ToList()` method.

Comment: As I reply on another answer, I don't know how List/IList/IEnumerable works together. Any good tutorial?

Comment: LINQ basically operates on two interfaces IEnumerable and IQuereable, not types. So, everything that implements IEnumerable also supports LINQ. If you want to see what data types implement IEnumerable. If you want I can compile the list of those for you.

Comment: but what it means operates on two interfaces? It basically store data in collection as List or IEnumerable.. that's what I don't understand (like IList is just the interface of List?!?!?).

Comment: It means that LINQ provides extension methods for IEnumerable interface and every class (like List<>, Queue<> etc) and other interfaces that implement this interface (like IList<>, for example).

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
protected IList<MyObject> offerte = new  List<MyObject>(MyObjects); 

// do your stuff
```